# Blogger Special Tags

Tags: blogger

Starting to code in a blogger page there are some concepts I have never come across. So to start with this simple code. You could assume the rest of the page is empty. What's necessary in a blogger's html? Where should I definitely not put certain parts of this code? Writing this alone wouldn't work right? Implement it in any way you like, I just need one way in which this code would work.
Thanks for all the help!

```xml
    <b:includable id='list'>
        <b:loop values='data:foo' var='item'>
            <li>
                <data:item/>
            </li>
        </b:loop>
    </b:includable>
    <ol>
        <b:include data='{ foo: ["Qux","Quux"] }' name='list'/>
        <b:include data='{ foo: ["Corge","Graul"] }' name='list'/>
        <b:include data='{ foo: ["Garply","Waldo"] }' name='list'/>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`b:includable` and `b:include`](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995) are widget tags so you can use them inside a widget.

In this example, you can see these tags used inside HTML widget.

```xml
    <b:section id='sec'>

      <b:widget id='HTML11' type='HTML' title='foo'>

        <b:includable id='main'>

            <ol>
                <b:include data='{ foo: ["Qux","Quux"] }' name='list'/>
                <b:include data='{ foo: ["Corge","Graul"] }' name='list'/>
                <b:include data='{ foo: ["Garply","Waldo"] }' name='list'/>
            </ol>

        </b:includable>

        <b:includable id='list'>

            <b:loop values='data:foo' var='item'>
                <li>
                    <data:item/>
                </li>
            </b:loop>

        </b:includable>

      </b:widget>

    </b:section>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok so, it wouldn't be possible to write the <ol> without it being inside a <b:includable>? And I thought the <b:includable>'s would only actualize when a <b:include> with a corresponding name referenced it. Sorry it's just that I've never used blogger's code. Do you have any pages or videos about blogger's html you'd recommend for a total beginner?

Comment: You can consider `b:includable` as a function definition in javascript and `b:include` as its calling. Blogger resources are limited, you can read [Blogger help docs](https://support.google.com/blogger#topic=3339243) and their default templates code. also [this blog](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/) is useful.

Comment: Right so how is <b:includable id="main"> ever being displayed? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: A widget must have one <b:includable id="main"> where you can use b:include from the same widget. also, you can make more b:includable but with different ids and include them in main.

Comment: ah, so never b:include with a name referencing any b:includable defined in another widget?
Like would this be wrong?
`
<b:widget>
  <b:includable id='main'>
    <b:include name='outOfBounds'/>
  </b.includable>
</b:widget>
<b:widget>
  <b:includable id='outOfBounds'/>
</b:widget>
`

Comment: Yes, each widget has its data but there are general or common tags can be used anywhere in theme like [data:view](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/1979/12/Ressource-data-view.html). I suggest you beside reading blogger docs carefully to learn Blogger API and how to get data from JSON feed to overcome blogger limitation. [This is a good start.](https://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/10/introduction-to-blogger-json-feeds-and-blogger-data-api.html)

Comment: @Bassam Sir, I am following the above links mentioned by you. I have a small question. Inside `blog widget` and few other widgets too, I see a `b: widget-settings` part. Any reference on widget settings? I didn't ask this as a separate question because I have not read anything on it. Please advise me.

Comment: These tags keep most of the gadget settings in XML. This means that you can export your theme to another blog without losing this information. [more info](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/2018/02/tags-b-widget-settings.html)

Comment: @Bassam Sir, I could understand and also modify most of the `blog widget` settings. Some I couldn't. For instance I found this inside the Blog widget `<b:widget-setting name='style.unittype'>TextAndImage</b:widget-setting>` I found no reference of this setting. Inside the theme as well I didn't find any other texts matching the `name` and the `value`.

Comment: There are no references other than that blog, But I think this setting and all `name='style....'`  are about the ad units between and inside posts when you set up an AdSense. Other settings come from the widget configuration.